# Type mismatch after adding Method to ActiveX Control used in C#

Tags: c#, vb6

I have to maintain a Control library written in VB6 before we move to .NET.
In this library is a Control (Name ist baseControl) which is hosted on other controls (childControl) where it's exposed as a Property.  All the Childcontrols are used in a C# Winforms application with no problem so far. Even some modifications in the baseControl worked as expected.

Now, when I add a new method to the baseControl, compile it, Import it to VS project so that the wrappers are newly created I get an type mismatch error at runtime when accessing the baseControl property in the childControl's.

After some test I found that it depends only on the new method. Compling with the former code worked like a charm.
Can anybody help me to get rid of the type mismatch?

Edit:  The code for the new method is pretty clear

```
Public Sub ApplyFilter(FilterLFN As Long)
'
'    Exit Sub
'ErrorHandler:
'    Call RaiseError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "ApplyFilter Function")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check your VB6 Compatibility settings, located in the VB6 IDE under Project properties and let us know what you have there.

Comment: The project compatibility ist set to binary with a link to the former build of the ocx. This has been the settings for years and worked well so far.

Comment: When you change between referencing the old OCX and new OCX, look in the C# project file and see if / how the reference changes. For instance, does the class ID version change?

Comment: The Guid is same as before. The VersionMinor changed from 1 to 2.

Comment: what is new method does? could you tell us or show the code.

Comment: There is something distinctive after VS created the new references there is a new interface "baseControl__v0" in the object browser besides the original interface "baseControl". How can the v0 interface be avoided?